# Keep form feed characters in CSS-string unchanged in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I avoid form feed characters to be parsed in a javascript string?

I have a variable holding this string

```
var css = 'content: "\f005"';
```

but the string is not left unchanged when I use it. E.g. `console.log(css)` gives `content: "005"`

My "solution" so far is this lille hack

```
decodeURIComponent(
    encodeURIComponent(css).replace(/%0C/g, "\\f")
);
```

Is there a better way?

### Use case (Update)

I am building a web widget, and I want a single JS lib without dependencies to CSS files. Therefore, when I build my project I read the minified css file, and inject it into the JS file as a string. When the JS lib is initialised at the client, it creates a `<style>` element and injects the css there.

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
var css = '...long css string...'; // form feed characters must be escaped
style.innerHTML = css;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

Comment: *"but the string is not left unchanged when I use it"* Well, yes, it basically is used unchanged: `\f` is a *formfeed*. The console doesn't display formfeeds.

Comment: You use `\\f` in the second snippet but are surprised `\f` doesn't work as expected in the first...?!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In my case I get a 3000 character long string describing css rules. I create a `<style>` element, and set `style.innerHtml = css`. But all rules containing ´\f...` doesn't work because I used javascript to set the styling. I think [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) is solving this problem, but it's experimental technology...

Comment: @deceze I use `\\f` because I need to escape the backslash. I don't feel surprised :) I'm just wondering if I can avoid that, and just use the string "untouched". But now I know [that's not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30713131/685352).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to write the literal characters `\f` in a Javascript string literal you need to escape the backslash:

```
var css = 'content: "\\f005"';
```

Otherwise `\f` is interpreted as form-feed character.

Comment: The string in my case is the content of a minified css file. And the css file uses `\fxxx` a lot. So I guess my only choice is to replace `\f` with `\\f` like I do?

Comment: If you're writing a **string literal** in JavaScript source code, you need to escape the backslash. If you get that content from elsewhere, JavaScript won't parse it like a string literal and not change it. It's unclear what your case is.

Comment: My case is: when I build my project I read a minified css file, and inject it into the JS file as a string literal. I have updated the question with an explanation why I wan't to do this.

Comment: Then you need to properly escape the string. You cannot simply inject some language into another language without worrying about escaping the values properly. In the case of injecting literals into Javascript, JSON-encode the value and all will be fine. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).